# How to parse an array of objects using data method of d3js and display it in tool tip?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, d3-force-directed

I am trying to implement the tool tip on hover of a particular node in force directed graph using d3 js.

Current Behavior: Tool tip is getting loaded but the text is not displayed properly, It is showing [object object] message instead of proper text message.

Expected Result: Tool tip should show the text in the below format:

```
Item Name: 'Item1',
Item Id: 'Item1',
Supplier: 'Supplier1'
```

How to achieve this ?

Working fiddle: [Tool tip](https://jsfiddle.net/vivekhegde99/7mzdjrv2/9/)

```
function showToolTip(selectedNode) {
  var itemDetails = [
            {'Item': selectedNode.name},
            {'Item Id': selectedNode.id},
            {'status': 'Normal'},
            {'Supplier': 'Supplier1'},
        ];
        tooltip.transition().duration(200).style('visibility', 'visible')
            .style('position', 'absolute').style('left', (d3.event.pageX) - 15 + 'px').style('top', (d3.event.pageY - 10) + 'px');
        tooltip.selectAll('div').data(itemDetails).enter().append('div').text(function (d, i) { return d; });
  }

function hideTooltip() {
 tooltip.selectAll('*').remove();
        tooltip.transition().duration(500).style('visibility', 'hidden');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The datum of each `<div>` is an object, and you're trying to pass the whole object to the `text()` method, hence the result you're seeing.

The best idea is dealing with the object inside the `text()` method, specifying exactly what you want to show (keys and values), and how. Meanwhile, a very simple and naive solution is this:

```
.text(function (d, i) { 
    return Object.entries(d)[0].join(": ");
});
```

Here is the forked JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ou85b3n1/

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
return `${Object.keys(d)[0]}: ${d[Object.keys(d)[0]]}`
```

Instead of:

```
return d
```

In your `showToolTip` function

You get this error (which is expected behaviour) because you're returning the full Object instead of a String.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f9kLjg7e/)

Answer (score 0):

```js
  function showToolTip(selectedNode) {
        tooltip.transition().duration(200).style('visibility', 'visible')
            .style('position', 'absolute').style('left', (d3.event.pageX) - 15 + 'px').style('top', (d3.event.pageY - 10) + 'px');
        tooltip.append('div').text(`Item: ${selectedNode.name}`);
        tooltip.append('div').text(`Item Id: ${selectedNode.id}`);
        tooltip.append('div').text(`Status: Normal`);
        tooltip.append('div').text(`Supplier: Supplier1`);
  }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nh4fdw03/1/